# FFMPEG blank tiny audio spot when concating

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, concatenation

I am trying to concat some mp3 audio files with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -y -i concat:"1.mp3|2.mp3|3.mp3" -c copy output.mp3
```

FFMPEG leaves some tiny empty audio spots between the concatenated files, looking output.mp3 with Audacity i have:
[image]

Is there some functionality on FFMPEG to avoid these empty audio spots?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [LAME Technical FAQ](http://lame.sourceforge.net/tech-FAQ.txt) has some relevant information. Here are some excerpts:

> ### Why does LAME add silence to the beginning each song?
>
> This is because of several factors:
>
> #### Decoder delay at start of file:
>
> All decoders I have tested introduce a delay of 528 samples.  That is,
>   after decoding an mp3 file, the output will have 528 samples of 0's
>   appended to the front. This is because the standard MDCT/filterbank
>   routines used by the ISO have a 528 sample delay.
>
> Furthermore, because of the overlapped nature of MDCT frames, the
>   first half of the first granule (1 granule=576 samples) doesn't have a
>   previous frame to overlap with, resulting in attenuation of the first
>   N samples.
>
> #### Encoder delay at start of file:
>
> ISO based encoders (BladeEnc, 8hz-mp3, etc) use a MDCT/filterbank
>   routine similar to the one used in decoding, and thus also introduce
>   their own 528 sample delay.  A .wav file encoded & decoded will have a
>   1056 sample delay (1056 samples will be appended to the beginning).
>
> Starting with LAME 3.55, we have a new MDCT/filterbank routine written
>   by Takehiro Tominaga with a 48 sample delay.

Refer to the [LAME Technical FAQ](http://lame.sourceforge.net/tech-FAQ.txt) for additional related answers and more in-depth information.

### Some options that aren't great but might do the job:

- Do you have to use MP3? Can you re-output your files to a different format such as PCM ("wav")? Note that simply re-encoding the existing MP3 files to another format will preserve the delay.
- You can use the [`afade` audio filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#afade) to add a fade out/fade in per section, or the [`atrim` audio filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#atrim) to possibly make the gaps less abrupt. However, filtering requires re-encoding.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It's help me to find how I've got 50ms blank at startup.